# How to escape a single quote in a dynamic expression with functions?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Need to insert a parameter into a string using the dynamic data function from the pipeline parameters.  Have tried backslash, double backslash, double single quote,@, @@, and other such nonsense.  Just need a simple way to escape a single quote in a string.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I actually found out.  It's 2 single quotes apparently.  I forgot to do it in both places, I had a single \ in the second place!

Comment: Thank you! I struggled for a while with this issue, and double apostrophes were the trick. My issue was to do with constructing a custom Lookup activity based on a parameter. Here is how the working query looks now: `@concat('select count(*) Count from ProcessedFiles where Filename=''', item().name, '''')`

Comment: No problem, glad someone else got some help out of my struggles!

Comment: @bdforbes in order to mimic formatted strings rather than endless concatenations : 
 `@replace('select count(*) Count from ProcessedFiles where Filename=''{MyFileName}''', '{MyFileName}', item().name)`